# Powershell for SharePoint Online active users

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, office-365-developer

I would like to know how to generate a list of all active users in a SharePoint Online site, and its sub sites in a csv file, including the following information:

- Date of creation of the csv file
- Last login and permissions for each user
- Groups that he belongs to

Even just a part of the answer could be useful.  I'm thinking about SharePoint Online shell.

Any other coding languages are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all SharePoint Online Active users using powershell by below given link steps. It is already available on MSDN.

[All SP Online Active Users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2777380)

If you want different kind on information than please find the details in below mentioned link.

[Details of all active users in SP Online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn683774.aspx)